# How to center links inside container in separate divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap (col/row) I am always making a mistake when I want to create separate sections, in one row/col.

Youtube links won't move to the center even they are in the same container. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

```
<div id="music" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0lufcRgZlA&ab_channel=BoBMArleySong1">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Natural Mystic</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4EZ8kpX3Os&ab_channel=AmazingDucker">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Three Little Birds</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHekNnySAfM&ab_channel=ReggaeLife">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Is This Love</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? version 4?

Comment: im using 5.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your text to be centered, be sure to use the classes [for aligning the text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

To clarify a bit:
If you need to center blocks within a container, you need to use `justify-content: center` on the container. Since this only works in combinatino with `display: flex` I also added `d-flex` class to column since a column isn't a flex-element by default in bootstrap.

A row already has `display: flex` so there is no need to set the `d-flex` class to it.

If you want to center text inside a block, you can do this via `text-align: center`

```css
img {max-width: 200px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="music" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0lufcRgZlA&ab_channel=BoBMArleySong1" class="text-center">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Natural Mystic</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4EZ8kpX3Os&ab_channel=AmazingDucker" class="text-center">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Three Little Birds</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHekNnySAfM&ab_channel=ReggaeLife" class="text-center">
                <img class="yt" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/08/56/social-2029117_960_720.png" alt="song.mp3">
                <span class="d-block">Is This Love</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i do this, add in a-tag class text-center.. only 'text/link' is moved in center... not the image too.

Comment: sorry, missed this since your images are quite huge. Then you need to center the content inside the columns, check my updated snipped (you were on the right track with justify-content-center, just on the wrong element)

Comment: yeah! Tnx bro! u help me alot! i waste to much time for this. Just to recap, first must to use d-flex and than option which i want? 
''class="container row d-flex justify-content-center''?
always going in this way?

Comment: I updated my answer since this would be too much text for a comment any other way, hope this helps and makes it a bit clearer!